# Is there a way to format this equation such that it doesn't look so crowded, and can appear across multiple rows?

Tags: equations, formatting, alignment

I have the following equation:
[image]

the code for which is:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
Centre~of~Mass \left \{ \bar{x}, \bar{y} \right \} = \left \{ \frac{M_{10}}{M_{00}} ,\frac{M_{01}}{M_{00}} \right \} = \left \{\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x, y)dxdy}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x, y)dxdy}, \frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}yf(x, y)dxdy}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x, y)dxdy} \right\}\label{eq:COM}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{center}
```

I am trying to get it across 2 rows so it doesn't look so crowded.

May I please ask how I can do this?

Comment: Which document class do tou employ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a single brace and move the words before the display.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The coordinates of the center of mass are given by
\begin{equation}\label{eq:COM}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\bar{x} &= \frac{M_{10}}{M_{00}} =
  \frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x, y)\,dx\,dy}
       {\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x, y)\,dx\,dy},
\\[1ex]
\bar{y} &= \frac{M_{01}}{M_{00}} =
  \frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}yf(x, y)\,dx\,dy}
       {\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x, y)\,dx\,dy}.
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You might prefer display style for the integral (I wouldn't):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\lfrac}[2]{\frac{\displaystyle#1}{\displaystyle#2}}

\begin{document}

The coordinates of the center of mass are given by
\begin{equation}\label{eq:COM}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\bar{x} &= \frac{M_{10}}{M_{00}} =
  \lfrac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x, y)\,dx\,dy}
       {\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x, y)\,dx\,dy},
\\[1ex]
\bar{y} &= \frac{M_{01}}{M_{00}} =
  \lfrac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}yf(x, y)\,dx\,dy}
       {\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x, y)\,dx\,dy}.
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't use `center` around `equation` and remember `\,` before differentials in integrals or differential forms in general (not in Leibniz-style derivatives, of course).

Comment: perfect, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You provided no information about fonts or page size, but this is an example, I stole a bit more space with `\!` than is ideal, but more or less OK

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\ddfrac[2]{\frac{\displaystyle#1}{\displaystyle#2}}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\textrm{Centre\,of\,Mass}  \{ \bar{x}, \bar{y}  \} 
& =\left\{ \ddfrac{M_{10}}{M_{00}} ,\ddfrac{M_{01}}{M_{00}} \right\} \\
&= \left \{\!\ddfrac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\!\!xf(x, y)\,dxdy}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\!f(x, y)\,dxdy}, \ddfrac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\!\!yf(x, y)\,dxdy}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\!f(x, y)\,dxdy}\! \right\}
\end{aligned}\label{eq:COM}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the `multlined` environment from `mathtools` (a superset of `amsmath`). I also added some imùprovement suxh as an upright differentail symbol  and wrote `Center of mass` as text:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \newcommand*{\dd}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
    \begin{multlined}
    \text{Centre~of~Mass }\left \{ \bar{x}, \bar{y} \right \} = \left \{ \frac{M_{10}}{M_{00}} ,\frac{M_{01}}{M_{00}} \right \} \\
      = \left \{\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x, y)\dd x \dd y} {\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x, y)\dd x \dd y}, \frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}yf(x, y)\dd x \dd y} {\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x, y)\dd x \dd y} \right\}\label{eq:COM}
    \end{multlined}
    \end{equation}

    \end{document}
```

[image]